# Does the instruction memory address change?

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

I am using `gdb` `disassemble my_fun`

```
#    0x7ffff5792a60 <PRIVATE0000000000579168>:  push   %r12
# => 0x7ffff5792a62 <PRIVATE0000000000579168+2>:    push   %r13
#    0x7ffff5792a64 <PRIVATE0000000000579168+4>:    push   %r14
```

I notice that the memory location of instructions e.g. `0x7ffff5792a60` is the same in different `gdb` debug sessions.

How is it possible? Is it a virtual memory address? Are we guaranteed to have the same memory address? Does it depend on how the application is compiled?

Comment: Depending on your operating system, your program may be loaded to different addresses on each invocation. Some compilers may also do this for you, to prevent certain security attacks.

Comment: Yes it's a virtual address. It's not guaranteed to be the same if you have ASLR/PIE.

Comment: didnt we just see this question almost verbatim recently?

Answer (score 2):

> I notice that the memory location of instructions e.g. 0x7ffff5792a60
>   is the same in different gdb debug sessions.

This is true because by default gdb disables randomization of the virtual address space. You can try to enable randomization with `set disable-randomization off` and likely your will see another instruction at address `0x7ffff5792a60`. See [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html#index-set-disable_002drandomization):

> set disable-randomization on
>
> This option (enabled by default in GDB) will turn off the native
>   randomization of the virtual address space of the started program.
>   This option is useful for multiple debugging sessions to make the
>   execution better reproducible and memory addresses reusable across
>   debugging sessions.

Comment: Note that even with randomization enabled the addresses in the main executable will not be randomized, unless the executable is built with `-pie` flag (which some GCC versions add by default, while other versions don't).